# Aligning Itemize and Description Item Labels

Tags: lists, enumitem

I would like to have the "bullets" of my itemize items line up horizontally with the start of the labels in my description lists. Here's an M(almost)WE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, varwidth, convert={size=640, density=600}, border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[description]{nosep, topsep=0pt, labelindent=1em}
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep, topsep=0pt, labelindent*=1em, label={\textbf{--}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \item Third Item
\end{itemize}

\begin{description}
    \item[Label] First Item
    \item[Another Label] Second Item
    \item[Yet Another Label] Third Item
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of my MWE]

I've played with many permutations of `labelindent(*)`, `leftmargin`, `itemindent`, etc. but can't seem to get the behavior I desire. Can someone explain the `enumitem` spacing system?

EDIT: The proposed solution with `wide` *almost* works:

```
\documentclass[10pt, varwidth, convert={size=640, density=600}, border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[description]{nosep, labelindent=1em}
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep, wide=1em, label={\textbf{--}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item with a really long amount of text that causes it to go onto a second line because I'm trying really hard to write a long sentence here.
    \item Third Item
\end{itemize}

\begin{description}
    \item[Label] First Item
    \item[Another Label] Second Item with a really long amount of text that causes it to go onto a second line because I'm trying really hard to write a long sentence here.
    \item[Yet Another Label] Third Item
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the modified MWE]

I'd like to have the same "hanging indent" behavior in both lists. In particular, I'd prefer to have continuing lines indented, matching the description list here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `wide` option (not the `widest`) and play with `leftmargin`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=4pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[description]{nosep, topsep=0pt, labelindent=1em, leftmargin=\dimexpr\leftmargini-\fontdimen2\font\relax}%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep, topsep=0pt, wide = 1em, label={\textbf{--}},leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item with a really long amount of text that causes it to go onto a second line because I'm trying really hard to write a long sentence here.
       \item Third Item
\end{itemize}

\begin{description}
    \item[Label] First Item.
    \item[Another Label] Second Item with a really long amount of text that causes it to go onto a second line because I'm trying really hard to write a long sentence here.
    \item[Yet Another Label] Third Item
\end{description}

\end{document} \setlist[description]{nosep, labelindent=1em}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep, wide=1em, label={\textbf{--}}}
```

[image]

Comment: `topsep=0pt` is unnecessary, isn't it? `nosep` already zeroes it ...

Comment: I guess so. As it was there, I left it. I noticed once that `noitemsep`, for instance, was not exactly `itemsep=0pt`, for a reason I don't really understand (probably the same reason which made a French humorist declare a temperature of –0° was colder than 0°.

Comment: Yes, but `topsep=0pt` is making it rigid, when it is almost certainly better to leave it stretchy. This way, there is stretchy glue between items, but none before the list, which means you may get more space between them than before the list. I guess that might be wanted, but it seems statistically unlikely.

Comment: I don't think it would  look nice anyway.

Comment: Well, yes, there is that. This is certainly going to look pretty ugly. I guess maybe it could be slightly less ugly, but killing all vertical space is never going to look good, as you say.

Comment: I do agree that it's not the prettiest. This is for my one-page résumé, where vertical space is at a premium.

Comment: The addition of `topsep` and `nosep` and friends is probably vestigial from my original creation of this years ago. That's interesting about the rigid vs. flexible lengths, and I think I'll go for the flexible ones!

Comment: Please see my edit for an update on the question with hanging indents.

Comment: @Scott: I've updated my answer. Is it what you want? B.t.w., beware the `widest` key is different from the `wide` key.

Comment: @Bernard That's exactly it! Your expression(?) in `leftmargin` is definitely above my current level of TeX literacy. Thanks for giving me something new to look into! :)